# How to fetch Entities, update in GWT, and save using JPA 2 in AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jpa, datanucleus

After I update some Entities in GWT, I would like to save them. However, when I try to persist them, it does not save when I look in the AppEngine admin interface. The Boolean has not changed.

#### Code

```
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    for (OnixUser s: admin) {
        log.info(s.email + ", " + s.isAdmin);
        em.merge(s);  
    }
    em.close();
```

#### Update with transaction

```
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (OnixUser s: admin) {
        log.info(s.email + ", " + s.isAdmin);
        OnixUser merged = em.merge(s);
        em.persist(merged);
//          em.persist(s);
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
```

Still did not save. No exceptions thrown.

#### Log

```
 Oct 16, 2013 3:19:10 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
 INFO: chloe@example.com, true
```

#### App Engine admin interface for OnixUser entity

[image: Imgur]

#### Log at FINEST level

```
FINE: Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@2fd9270d
Oct 16, 2013 4:03:14 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection
FINE: Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@31c1f89d for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@6977c57b in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@2b1f5f6b]
Oct 16, 2013 4:03:14 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: chloe@example.com, true
Oct 16, 2013 4:03:14 PM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser@48ef6e99" (id="com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser:6456332278300672") has a lifecycle change : "P_CLEAN"->"P_NONTRANS"
Oct 16, 2013 4:03:14 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$1 managedConnectionPostClose
FINE: Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@31c1f89d for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@6977c57b in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@2b1f5f6b]
Oct 16, 2013 4:03:14 PM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser@48ef6e99" (id="com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser:6456332278300672") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Oct 16, 2013 4:03:14 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.AppEngineAuthentication$AppEngineUserRealm disassociate
FINE: Ignoring disassociate call for: chloe@example.com
```

Comment: I have not used GWT, but your code does not starts/commits a transaction using em.getTransaction().begin() and em.getTransaction().commit(). Without a transaction, the entity manager does not make any changes to database as per JPA specification.

Comment: @Shailendra I thought it was optional, but I added transactions and it still did not save when viewed through the admin interface or when the page is reloaded.

Comment: You do not need the call to persist, as the object pointed by "merged" will be managed and any further changes will be persisted automatically on transaction commit. You can enable the sql logging to see if there is indeed any SQL  generated by this operation.

Comment: @Shailendra I tried with and without .persist(), and restarted server in between. How do I turn on SQL logging?

Comment: Which persistence provider are you using for JPA ?

Comment: @Shailendra DataNucleus. It comes with AppEngine. `org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl`

Answer (score 0):

If inspite of using transactions your data is not persisted then best way would be to try the logging to see what's happening underneath. As you using DataNucleus as your persistence provider, you can refer to this [link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/logging.html) to configure
the SQL logging. The information  relevant to you is given near the end of page.

Comment: Ok I modified WEB-INF/logging.properties and restarted the server, but it doesn't print any additional information: http://pastie.org/8407353

Comment: Ok I had to stop & start server, not just reload. Used `.level=FINEST` 
`DataNucleus.level=FINEST` and it resulted in this log: http://pastie.org/8407382

Comment: Can you post relevant persistence.xml. What I want to see is whether the transaction type is JTA or RESOURCE_LOCAL. In case its former then you probably need to inject Entity manager instead of creating yourself.

Comment: The user is using GAE. There is no such SQL. Obviously GAEs plugin for JPA does print out a lot of log info at DEBUG level including all PUTs to the datastore.

Comment: Then it looks like I have misunderstood the environment.